# How to create monitoring thread?

Tags: linux, pthreads, mutex

I got a question while I'm doing for ray-tracing stuff.

I have created multiple threads to split whole image to be processed and let it process its allocated task. Threads work well as it is intended. I would like to monitor the work progress in real-time.

To resolve this problem, I have created one more thread to monitor current state.
Here is the monitoring pseudo-code:

```
/* Global var */
int cnt = 0; // count the number of row processed


void* render_disp(void* arg){ // thread for monitoring current render-processing 

    /* monitoring global variable and calculate percentage to display */
    double result = 100.*cnt/(h-1);
    fprintf(stderr,"\r3.2%f%% of image is processed!", result);
}

void* process(void* arg){ // multiple threads work here

    // Rendering process
    for(........)
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
       cnt++;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

       for(........)

}
```

I wrote the code for initialization of pthread and mutex in *main()* function.
Basically, I think this monitoring thread should display current state but this thread seems to be called only once and quit.
How do I change this code to this thread function to be called until the whole rendering is finished?

Comment: You need a loop in the monitoring thread: while (!end) { nanosleep(...); result = ...; fprintf(...result); }

Comment: Yes, the thread function is called only once per thread.  This is normal.  If you want it to perform repetitions of some task then you achieve that in any of the ways you would achieve the same in single-threaded code.  In particular, looping is a good all-around choice.